# Tableau rawsqlagg_real

Tags: tableau-api

Could somebody please give me a little guidance on rawsqlagg_real function in Tableau. What is right syntax for it when it is used to get data from MySQL. 
I used it as per my understanding but I am getting an error "No such column [__measure__3]".

Code:

```
 RAWSQLAGG_REAL("select count(Film Id) from flavia.TableforThe_top_10percent_of_the_user where count(distinct(User Id)) = %1",[it sucks])
```

Comment: Could you show the code that you've tried?

Comment: Thank you Andrew for giving attention to my question.
Here is my code:
RAWSQLAGG_REAL("select count(`Film Id`) from flavia.`TableforThe_top_10percent_of_the_user` where count(distinct(`User Id`)) = %1",[it sucks])

Comment: I'd go ahead and add that code to your question rather than putting it in the comments. It'll make it more readable and more accessible to people trying to reference this question.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using Tableau 9?

Comment: I am using Tableau 9.0.

Comment: There are usually much more efficient and maintainable ways to analyze data in Tableau than using Raw SQL (or even custom SQL). Computed sets, LOD calculations, data blending, table calcs can usually accomplish what you need. I'd avoid raw sql, and even custom sql, except in the rare cases that you absolutely need it, say to access a non standard function provided by your database server.

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question with the tables you have (possibly simplified) and the calculation you wish to accomplish (possibly simplified). Understanding SQL concepts is very helpful, but you'll get further with Tableau quickly if you don't try to revert to using SQL from within Tableau usually. Its faster to let Tableau generate the SQL in response to your actions.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues here

1. Instead of WHERE, use HAVING
2. You have column names like Film Id, you should write them as 'Film Id' instead

Though I must say that it is better to do with LOD calculations as Tableau will be able to do better query optimizations that way. Plus it is less error prone and much easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

I find another issue here in addition to using `having` instead of `where`. The filter value should be numeric, or the operator should be `like` and not `=`.

```
where count(distinct(User Id)) = **%1**
```